# Не отображаются новые данные в sqllite после миграции из python django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Создал миграцию в django, передал данную миграцию в sqllite, а она не отображается. Во-вторник картинке как должно быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное, что-то неправильно сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы забываете применить миграцию.
Напомню, после операции

```
python manage.py make migrations
```

Необходимо применить эти миграции (на данный момент они просто созданы):

```
python manage.py migrate
```